# How to embed a widget in angular

Tags: angular, widget

I have got a script tag of a widget to embed in my website ,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.enetscores.com/FWA003AAB2AA750CFB"></script>`

But on adding it to my template nothing appears. Can somebody help please

Answer (score -1):

use Iframe if it's a independent widget inside you app.

or you can try HTML custom element injection (this works in latest browser)

or you can have a look at this the Angular way of making small widgets and using in another App

https://angular.io/guide/elements